# can't click on Flash Local Storage Allow/Deny pop-up

Tags: flash, flash-player

On certain sites using Local Storage, a pop-up appears instead of the Flash-based application, with the following message:

```
Adobe Flash Player Settings
Local Storage

www.example.com is requesting permission to store 
information on your computer.

Requested: up to 1 MB
Currently Used: 101 KB

[Folder icon] [Allow] [Deny]
```

And it's impossible to click either button. That is, clicking has no effect. Therefore, the application can't be used any more.

How to allow or deny this setting?

Comment: It appears you have just raised the security of your Java installation.  You can adjust the level of security through the Java Control Panel Applet.

Comment: What does Java have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get around the problem by navigating to the website in Opera, where there was no problem clicking on the buttons. The buttons were unclickable when using Firefox, Chrome and IE.